# Why does my program produce no output while it's compiling fine?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a two dimensional array. **I am able to compile but not able to run**

```
public class Arraytest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, k = 0;
        int test[][] = new int[4][5];
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                test[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; k++)
                System.out.print(test[i][j] + " ");

            System.out.println();    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you mix `j` and `k` and therefore have an endless loop

Comment: yes i found that stil i am getting into infinite loop

Comment: @gaurav.ncst: You have the same issue in your second loop.

Answer (score 7):

You have an endless loop: `for(j=0;j<5;k++)`, you have to write `for(j=0;j<5;j++)`

You increment `k` instead of `j`

Answer (score 0):

You have an endless loop. You are incrementing `k` instead of `j`:

```
for(j=0;j<5;k++)
```

You should change it both times to

```
for(j=0;j<5;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here... this should work. Just change your sub-loops making it `j++` instead of `k++` both top and bottom

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      int i, j, k = 0;
      int test[][] = new int[4][5];
      for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
              test[i][j] = k;
              k++;
          }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
              System.out.print(test[i][j] + " ");
          System.out.println();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mixed up the k and j variables in the second for-loop "block". When I alter it to:

```
   ... 
   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
       System.out.print(test[i][j] + " ");

      System.out.println();    
    }
    ...
```

I get the following printed to my console:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19
```

Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Arraytest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, k = 0;
        int test[][] = new int[4][5];
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                test[i][j] = k;
                k++;
           }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.print(test[i][j] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

you can resolve this problem

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain it. What is the difference between your code and theirs?

Comment: Moreover, your code where false (A `{`where missing)